# Plant Your Thoughts

Tags: riddle

Many people don't know my true form

You may see me within a sandstorm

My green is ancient

Before you use me, be patient

And a famous entity is warm

Hint

> Lines 3 and 4 refer to paper, but the answer isn't  a tree

Name the plant

Comment: do line 3 and 4 refers to money in any way?

Comment: No, there are no references to money

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are:

> The papyrus plant.

Many people don't know my true form

> This is a plant that many people aren't very familiar with.

You may see me within a sandstorm

> Papyrus was famously used by ancient Egyptians, Egypt being almost synonymous with a land of desert.

My green is ancient

> This green plant was used by ancient Egyptians for many things -- including for paper. Also, during the construction of papyrus paper, the color is transformed from green to a shade of brown.

Before you use me, be patient

> In the construction of papyrus paper, you need to hang it up to dry before you can use it. Thus, you must be patient.

And a famous entity is warm

> This one I am not sure. If warmth is in reference to the sun - the plant must grow in full sun, and parts of the plant may have been used ceremonially in worship of Ra (the sun God).

Comment: @XavierStanton Nice! That connection didn’t even occur to me. I always just associated him with the font.

Comment: @XavierStanton *Please* stop giving the answer in comments. As I've pointed out to you a few times already, we put answers in spoilers here to preserve the mystery for future would-be solvers. Doing this is of little benefit if you then give the answer away in the comments.  Try being more indirect in alluding to the answer instead of saying or referencing it directly, or using [ROT-13](http://www.rot13.com/) encoding or similar if you must.  Your comment has been deleted.

Comment: I'm a bit late, but sorry about that. thanks for deleting the comment

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is

> tumbleweed

Many people don't know my true form

> The tumbleweed we know in cowboy movies is not the living form of the plant.

You may see me within a sandstorm

> You sometimes observe a tumbleweed rolling in sandstorm or desert (like in cowboy movies)

My green is ancient

> When you observe the usually known form of tumbleweed, it is not green anymore but is used to be.

Before you use me, be patient

> You have to wait before your tumbleweed plant gives you is "moving form"

And a famous entity is warm

> I guess it is the burning bush but it wasn't really a tumbleweed. It was more like a bramble

Name the plant

> tumbleweed again

Comment: No, but I see where you are coming from

Answer (score 1):

This might be:

> **Plant of Immortality (Aloe Vera)**
> The Amazing Properties of Aloe Vera like healing wounds, keeping healthy, beautiful and around 50 more makes this plant very useful. But the people are not aware of the benefits of the Aloe Vera. Though, people in ancient time used this widely for the different purpose.

Comment: Incorrect, but good try